# Format decimal when using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have a text file that I'm trying to insert into a SQL server table using `SqlBulkCopy`. The text file has rows such as:

```
1;2272575;2.5;abc
2;2272575;4.7;efg
```

However, I get the exception:

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type money of the specified target column

Is there a way to tell the SqlBulkCopy class to convert certain columns to decimal?